# doctrine 2: tell proxy class to ignore entity methods

Tags: proxy, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am putting into my entities some methods that do not require entity's parameters to be loaded from database and i would like that proxy generator would ignore these methods and not include any wrappers with `$this->__load();` for them.

Two other solutions would be to use static methods since they are ignored or write custom proxies classes, but I would prefer auto generation with some doctrine annotation.

Is there a way to do that? Or should I use static methods (since I'm auto generating proxy classes)?

Comment: what do you need it for?

Comment: I store Zend Framework's validation classes and their options inside my entities. So I don't actually need entity to have loaded params from database to get it's validators.

Comment: You ever find a way of resolving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I moved out of PHP world eventually :)